# Can we build two messages with same MD5 but different size?

Tags: md5

Can we build two messages with same MD5 but different size?

I researched MD5 collisions, but everything I found targets messages of the same size.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because generic requests for help are not considered concise enough to be answered conclusively (and reference requests to specific files are considered off topic as well).

Comment: @kelalaka: This is not a duplicate of [_Create a MD5 collision on two given files with an identical prefix_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87531/555), nor covered by [corkami](https://github.com/corkami/collisions/blob/master/README.md) or [hashclash](https://github.com/cr-marcstevens/hashclash/blob/master/README.md), because the "different size" constraint changes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was [moved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87757/555) following closing of the question.