# How to create two partly similar plaintexts with same MD5 hash value?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5

The problem I'd like to solve looks like this:

There are two plaintexts which differ in length and letters, but contain a few common strings. The first few words and the last few words are the same, and there are some common words in the middle as well (sometimes in the same order). The two texts have pretty much the opposite meaning.

The goal is to modify these syntactically but not semantically, and achieve the variants' MD5 hash (or at least the hash values' first 4 bytes) to be the same.
[I know, that MD5 hash collisions can occur](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value), but how could I implement it in a programming language (e.g. Python) which is not brute force? Is there any way to check which letters to change?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, so I'm not asking for the exact code. The sites and posts I've found about the MD5 collision weren't that helpful.

Comment: Since this is homework, I'll just give you a hint: I expect that looking for cryptographical weaknesses in MD5 is not the best approach.  Instead, consider: if we replace MD5 with a strong hash, how would you attack this problem?

Comment: If it's another (strong) algorithm, then collisions won't occur, so the problem is unsolvable. Even if some parts of the two texts match, the avalanche effect makes it impossible. Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: "(or at least the hash values' first 4 bytes)"

Comment: You're right. Inspecting the algorithm, the digest's first four bytes is computable from the inital values _a0_ and _d0_, but the hash function is provided:
```from Crypto.Hash import MD5  def trhash(x)  
h = MD5.new()  
h.update(x)  
return h.digest()[0:4]```

Comment: Suppose you had a perfect hash where you would truncate the output to 4 bytes, how many evaluations would you need to find a collision?